# Event doesnt fire in chrome addon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I've been back and forth with this problem. What I want is to execute som piece of code (in a injected.js file) when a button is pressed on the website. I want to run code that I've written myself.

This should be do-able? I've looked it up, and this is taken from the developer docs:

*Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They **have access to the DOM** of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page. **It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript executing on the page it is running on**. The same is true in reverse: JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any variables defined by content scripts.*

As can be seen in the example, also found on the same page (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment) I should be able to attach a click event to something and the execute code from the same .js file when that button is clicked? Right?

Anyway, here's the code I've written:

```
$sidebar = $('<div><div></div></div>')
    .css('background', '#eee')
    .css('width', '20%')
    .css('position', 'fixed')
    .css('right', '0px')
    .css('top', '0px')
    .css('height', '100%');

$form = $('<br/><center><div class="input-append">\
  <input class="span2" id="add_cat_input"  type="text">\
  <button class="btn" type="button">Add category</button>\
  </div>\
  <div class="input-append"><select id="categories">\
  <option>A</option>\
  <option>B</option>\
  <option>C</option>\
  <option>D</option>\
  <option>E</option>\
</select>\
<button class="btn" type="button">Edit</button><button class="btn" type="button">Delete</button>\
</div></center>');

$('body').prepend($sidebar);
$sidebar.append($form);

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("add_cat_input"));
    document.getElementById("add_cat_input").addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('hej');
}, false);
});
```

But nothing happends when I press 'Add category'.

Can anyone explain why? Am I doing it wrong?

The code above is from myscript.js.
Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name" : "πSpend",
  "version" : "0.1",
  "description" : "Creates a piechart of the spendings in your bankaccount.",
  "permissions": [ "cookies", "tabs", "http://*/*", "contextMenus" ],
  "icons": { "16": "cookie.png", "48": "cookie.png", "128": "cookie.png" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "cookie.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://internetbanken.privat.nordea.se/*"],
      "css": [ "bootstrap.min.css" ],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "raphael-min.js", "g.raphael-min.js", "g.pie-min.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

On the way I tried to use some form of message posting instead, but this line:

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect();
```

Gets me this error:

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Comment: The element `add_cat_input` which is bound to `click` listener - is NOT a button, but a text field. The button "Add category" does not have an id.

Comment: BTW, you `permissions` section does not include `https://*/*`, while content script is injected into "https://...".

Comment: Will try that in a second Stan, that could be the problem :)

Comment: Dude, that did it! Thanks for notice! Make an answer and I'll accept it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `add_cat_input` which is bound to `click` listener - is NOT a button, but a text field. The button "Add category" does not have an id in your code.